# Oracle Apex: how to redirect to specific page after login

Tags: redirect, oracle-apex

in Oracle Apex i want to redirect users to their specific pages after login as per their user types. please help how i can do this. currently tried on Page 1 (Home) -> Before Header - Branches - Function Returning a URL (Redirect) and my code is as below (to check i hard coded page no. in url's)

```
declare
  x number:=1;
  myurl varchar2(255);
begin
  if :SESSION_USER_TYPE in ('admin', 'zoneadmin') then
     x := 1;
     myurl := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:1:&SESSION.::::P1_ID:&SESSION_USER_ID.';
  elsif :SESSION_USER_TYPE in ('rider') then
     x := 24;
     myurl := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:24:&SESSION.::::P24_ID:&SESSION_USER_ID.';
  end if;
  return myurl;
end;
```

after login, google says:
127.0.0.1 redirected you too many times.
try clearing your cookies
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

even i removed all chrome cookies from settings. please help to overcome the situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your application have deep linking enabled ? If this is disabled then the user will always be redirected to the home page, even if you pass a page in the url. That would explain the too many redirects.

Also, you should remove the block to redirect to page 1. The user is on page 1 so this will get you in an endless loop. An easier solution would be to create a branch (Function Returning a URL (Redirect)) with code

```
declare
  x number:=1;
  myurl varchar2(255);
begin
  x := 24;
  myurl := 'f?p=&APP_ID.:24:&SESSION.::::P24_ID:&SESSION_USER_ID.';
  return myurl;
end;
```

and serverside condition of type "Expression" with code

```
:SESSION_USER_TYPE in ('rider')
```

Comment: thanks Koen, it is not even redirecting to Home page, but only shows google error page and nothing else. btw how i can enable deep linking feature in apex? please guide.

Comment: Shared Components > Security attributes

Comment: enable this, cleared all cookies, exit browser, run again, login to application, but still same google error message. is there any setting required in login page? or anything else?

Comment: Think I found the issue - check updated answer.

Comment: thanks Koen for update in previous post, but i do not have only 1 and 24, here are more user types which needs to redirect to their specific pages. i need to extend the code for Function Returning a URL (Redirect) for other user types? or i misunderstood?

Comment: Up to you how you implement it. Did my solution work ? You could have multiple branches with each branch having it's own server side condition or one branch with all the code.? Just make sure you don't branch back to page 1.

Comment: very sorry @Koen for delay, i have used "Page or URL" approach, created 3 branches with server side condition "Value = " and it works fine for me. thanks very much for your efforts to guide me, help me. with best regards.