# how to open a non-public apex page via url

Tags: oracle-apex

probably it's browser related but my exact urls don't work as they should, if the page requires authentication.

for instance, if I share this link with users

```
https://my_srv/f?p=100:2
```

they would be prompted for authentication, then APEX will redirect them to the page 1, home page.

Is there a way to tell APEX to go to the page that pointed out in the url after authentication?

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70065215/oracle-apex-how-to-redirect-to-specific-page-after-login

Comment: but in order to get the benefit of deep linking, users have to be authenticated at least one of the applications in the same instance. Am I wrong?

Comment: I was wrong, enabling Deep Linking was the answer. Thank you very much @Littlefoot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your application's shared components -> security attributes.
There you would see deep linking: [image]

Change your settings (rejoins sessions & deep linking) for your requirements.
Then your URL would be redirecting users to the specific page after login.

See:
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4181586/how-to-open-page-of-application-directly-from-external-link
for further details.

Comment: thank you Cengiz, tesekkur ederim. It worked.

Comment: my pleasure, have a nice day